# How to move multiple PHP array elements using keys?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I need to move elements from array using cms_before OR cms_after keys.
For example, Folder B is after Folder A using is GUID (0E3B180C-F4AA-484F-A19D-318E6D4D2A6C).

The array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cms_parent_node] => 0
            [cms_before] => 
            [cms_after] => 
            [cms_guid] => 0E3B180C-F4AA-484F-A19D-318E6D4D2A6C
            [cms_title] => Dossier A
            [level] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [cms_parent_node] => 0E3B180C-F4AA-484F-A19D-318E6D4D2A6C
                            [cms_before] => 
                            [cms_after] => 
                            [cms_guid] => D94840DC-7CD8-E7AA-7C69-A237306D24E6
                            [cms_title] => Dossier A.A
                            [level] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [cms_parent_node] => D94840DC-7CD8-E7AA-7C69-A237306D24E6
                                            [cms_before] => 
                                            [cms_after] => 
                                            [cms_guid] => 1B20700B-70F0-FFE5-47AC-3DA35460C702
                                            [cms_title] => Dossier A.A.A
                                            [level] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [cms_parent_node] => 0
            [cms_before] => 
            [cms_after] => 1CBF252E-0C28-36E9-D5DF-66F361FB00E9
            [cms_guid] => 57F64452-B6BE-3039-F30A-1BE413936A71
            [cms_title] => Dossier C
            [level] => Array
                (
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [cms_parent_node] => 0
            [cms_before] => 
            [cms_after] => 57F64452-B6BE-3039-F30A-1BE413936A71
            [cms_guid] => 44269A70-FF01-EB17-7437-8B1EFB746E0D
            [cms_title] => Dossier D
            [level] => Array
                (
                )
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [cms_parent_node] => 0
            [cms_before] => 
            [cms_after] => 0E3B180C-F4AA-484F-A19D-318E6D4D2A6C
            [cms_guid] => 1CBF252E-0C28-36E9-D5DF-66F361FB00E9
            [cms_title] => Dossier B
            [level] => Array
                (
                )
        )
)
```

The return array must be in this order :

```
A
  A.A
   A.A.A
B
C
D
```

The result:

```
Array
   (
       [0] => Array
           (
               [cms_parent_node] => 0
               [cms_before] =>
               [cms_after] =>
               [cms_guid] => 0E3B180C-F4AA-484F-A19D-318E6D4D2A6C
               [cms_title] => Dossier A
               [level] => Array
                   (
                       [0] => Array
                           (
                               [cms_parent_node] => 0E3B180C-F4AA-484F-A19D-318E6D4D2A6C
                               [cms_before] =>
                               [cms_after] =>
                               [cms_guid] => D94840DC-7CD8-E7AA-7C69-A237306D24E6
                               [cms_title] => Dossier A.A
                               [level] => Array
                                   (
                                       [0] => Array
                                           (
                                               [cms_parent_node] => D94840DC-7CD8-E7AA-7C69-A237306D24E6
                                               [cms_before] =>
                                               [cms_after] =>
                                               [cms_guid] => 1B20700B-70F0-FFE5-47AC-3DA35460C702
                                               [cms_title] => Dossier A.A.A
                                               [level] => Array
                                                   (
                                                   )

                                           )

                                   )

                           )

                   )

           )


    [1] => Array
        (
            [cms_parent_node] => 0
            [cms_before] => 
            [cms_after] => 0E3B180C-F4AA-484F-A19D-318E6D4D2A6C
            [cms_guid] => 1CBF252E-0C28-36E9-D5DF-66F361FB00E9
            [cms_title] => Dossier B
            [level] => Array
                (
                )

        )

       [2] => Array
           (
               [cms_parent_node] => 0
               [cms_before] =>
               [cms_after] => 1CBF252E-0C28-36E9-D5DF-66F361FB00E9
               [cms_guid] => 57F64452-B6BE-3039-F30A-1BE413936A71
               [cms_title] => Dossier C
               [level] => Array
                   (
                   )

           )

       [3] => Array
           (
               [cms_parent_node] => 0
               [cms_before] =>
               [cms_after] => 57F64452-B6BE-3039-F30A-1BE413936A71
               [cms_guid] => 44269A70-FF01-EB17-7437-8B1EFB746E0D
               [cms_title] => Dossier D
               [level] => Array
                   (
                   )

           )


   )
```

Comment: Can you post your test data set, please?  I'm looking for something that will let us show you a programmatic solution.  Description of the data we need would be something along the lines of SSCCE.org

Comment: Try formulating a question.

Comment: I'm having difficult seeing what your exact problem is.  The array seems to already be in the order you need it.

Comment: Ok sorry, i would like to move an element using a specific position in array.

Comment: As I read it, he want a 1 dimensional array, with sublevels prefixed by spaces. But indead, the question is quite unclear.

Comment: [whathaveyoutried.com](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)

Comment: I edit my question adding the result. As you can see, i want to order my arrays using cms_before, cms_after , these keys manage the position of the elements matching the cms_guid from the other entries. But i have to move elements to specific position and i don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.

```
function reorder($folders) {
  $current = null;
  $after = array();

  foreach ($folders as &$folder) {
    if ($folder['cms_after']) $after[$folder['cms_after']] =& $folder;
      else $current =& $folder;
  }

  $list = array();
  while ($current) {
    $list[] = $current;
    $current = isset($after[$current['cms_guid']]) ? $after[$current['cms_guid']] : null;
  }

  return $list;
}
```

Work on your question asking skills....

Comment: Thank you for your answer but i doesnt want to use cms_title BUT cms_after or cms_before. The match must be made with cms_guid

Comment: Check the new answer. It should do what you want.

Comment: That it ! It works great ! how can you change your function adding possibility using cms_before if define.

Comment: You should either use cms_after or cms_before, but not both. If the data is consistent it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Yes i will do this and set an option "put on top" :)
Thank a lot.

Comment: I should used also cms_order = 1 ... but the order is dynamic and can be from anywhere ... :) thanks

Comment: Your code does not work in sub level if i had A.A.C A.A.B, have an idea ?

Comment: This only works on 1 level. If you need more levels, use recursion.

Comment: i try:
private function _reorder($nodes)
    {
        $current = null;
        $after = array();

        foreach ($nodes as &$node) {
            if ($node['cms_after']) $after[$node['cms_after']] =& $node;
            else $current =& $node;
            if (sizeof($node['level'])) {
                $this->_reorder($node['level']);
            }
        }

        $list = array();
        while ($current) {
            $list[] = $current;
            $current = isset($after[$current['cms_guid']]) ? $after[$current['cms_guid']] : null;
        }

        return $list;
    }